# Zeebe Java. Correct way to store json in variable

Tags: java, json, objectmapper, camunda, zeebe

I use java/kotlin + zeebe and I want to store my dto object as JSON.
When I use `objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dto)` my final json in operate looks like `"{\"id\":\"10\"}`.

I think zeebe can store JSON without escaping characters. Could you tell me what is the best way to compose JSON from DTO object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.
For correct JSON saving I use `objectMapper.convertValue(dto, ObjectNode::class.java)`

After that in operate showed correct JSON without escaping characters.
If you want to store array of object use `ArrayNode` class.

That's helped me